# Bounded solutions of 2nd order IVP

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the pair of initial value problems on the real line:

$$y'' + (x^4 - \lambda)y = 0, \ \ (\ y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 0 \ ) \ \text{ or } (\ y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 1 \ ) $$

One can find numerically for both problems that there are discrete values of $\lambda$ for which $\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} y(x) = 0$. Such solutions are bounded.

These values of $\lambda$ with the bounded solutions correspond to energy eigenstates of a particular quantum system; that's the original motivation for this equation.

My question is: how would one prove mathematically that there are infinitely many such $\lambda$ and that the $\lambda$ are discrete?

Comment: i don't know all the details off hand but this problem is called the sturm-liouville problem. it is known that it has a discrete spectrum. and many other properties.

Comment: I'm rusty on ODE theory ... thanks: that's the name that unlocks references for me. I'll take it from here.